# Erro na instalação do kivy

Tags: python, pip, python-kivy, kivy

Não consigo instalar o kivy no meu computador, nunca mexi com pip antes, estou colocando os comandos no cmd e dá erro.

Estou executando os seguintes comandos:

```
python -m pip install docutils pygments pypiwin32 kivy.deps.sdl2 kivy.deps.glew
python -m pip install kivy.deps.gstreamer
python -m pip install kivy.deps.angle
```

Esses 3 comandos não apresentam erros na instalação. Mas quando faço:

```
python -m pip install kivy
```

É que apresenta erro. Executei no cmd na área de trabalho e na pasta onde está instalado o python (3.8). Também utilizei tanto o cmd quanto o powershell e dá o mesmo erro, que é:

ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1: python setup.py egg_info Check the logs for full command output.

Comment: A propósito, uso o Windows 10.

Comment: checou o log para ver se tem mais detalhes?

Comment: não sei como faço isso @RicardoPontual

Answer (score 0):

Funcionou aqui pra mim, peguei de um repositório gringo do github:

Não é provável que lançemos uma versão 1.11.1 para 3.8 para pypi. No entanto, você pode instalar o kivy master usando:

```
pip install kivy[base] kivy_examples --pre --extra-index-url https://kivy.org/downloads/simple/.
```

copia do pip até o `.` e cola no `cmd`
espero que de certo.